# Can anyone help me converting SQL to linq query. I tried but failed

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my SQL query working fine in SQL:

```
select ld.FolderId, count(ld.LeadId) LeadID, sum(note.noteCount) NoteCount, count(ld.CallResultId) Calls 
from LeadsDetails ld 
    left join 
    (
        select lnh.LeadId, Count(lnh.NoteId) as noteCount 
        from [dbo].[LeadNoteHistory] lnh 
        group by lnh.LeadId
    )note
    on note.LeadId=ld.LeadId 
group by ld.FolderId
```

I tried -

```
var query = 
    from lead in _context.LeadsDetails
    join note in _context.LeadNoteHistories
    on lead.LeadId equals note.LeadId into g
    from notes in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group lead by lead.FolderId into grp
    select new
    {
        FolderId = g.FolderId,
        LeadID = g.LeadId,
        NoteCount = notes.NoteId,
        Call = lead.CallResultId
    };
```

Cannot get the right result. Please tell what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the result you are after?

Comment: see the sql query. i want to create exact query in LINQ

Comment: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: i already tried but unable to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variable 'g' in select clause later. You need to use variable 'grp'. You also need to modify the final group by. I tried modifying, see if this works:

```
var query = 
    from lead in _context.LeadsDetails
    join note in _context.LeadNoteHistories
    on lead.LeadId equals note.LeadId into g
    from notes in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new {lead,notes} lead by lead.FolderId into grp
    select new
    {
        FolderId = grp.Key,
        LeadID = grp.Count(),
        NoteCount = grp.Count(x=>x.notes!=null),
        Call = grp.Count()
    };
```

Comment: almost- just see that in the SQL there are `Sum` and `Count` for the fields

Comment: NoteCount = grp.Count(x=>x.notes!=null),  unable to access 'notes' here

Answer (score 0):

For translating SQL to LINQ,

1. Translate subselects as separate variables
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new { }`) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a join variable and doing another `from` from the join variable followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Here is your SQL translated:

```
var rightside = from lnh in dbo.LeadNoteHistory
                group lnh by lnh.LeadId into lnhg
                select new { LeadId = lnhg.Key, noteCount = lnhg.Count() };

var ans = from ld in dbo.LeadsDetails
          join note in rightside on ld.LeadId equals note.LeadId into notej
          from note in notej.DefaultIfEmpty()
          group new { ld, note } by ld.FolderId into ldnoteg
          select new {
              FolderId = ldnoteg.Key,
              LeadID = ldnoteg.Select(lng => lng.ld.LeadId).Count(),
              NoteCount = ldnoteg.Select(lng => lng.note.noteCount).Sum(),
              Calls = ldnoteg.Select(lng => lng.ld.CallResultId).Count()
          };
```

I left the `LeadID` definition as in your SQL, but that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but these lines are giving errors.                         LeadID = ldnoteg.ld.LeadId.Count(),
NoteCount = ldnoteg.note.noteCount.Sum(),
Calls = ldnoteg.ld.CallResultId.Count()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't translate the group access correctly - I fixed it. Looking at the LINQ versus the SQL it is obvious the SQL has a number of errors: LeadId shouldn't be a `count`, there is no difference between `count(ld.LeadId)` and `count(ld.CallResultId)` without a `DISTINCT`.